# Wordpress Add, Update and Get Post Meta not working

Tags: php, wordpress, post-meta

The below code is added into a page template file, when someone loads the page it will add the post meta if it didn't exist, it will update the post meta if it did exist. When I get the post meta and then return it, the outcome is "Array".

It leads me to believe the post meta is not being made or the get isn't working.

```
global $post;
if ( ! add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'offer_voucher_evergreen_deadline', '2018-11-16 13:00:00')) { 
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'offer_voucher_evergreen_deadline', '2018-11-16 13:00:00');
}

$test = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'offer_voucher_evergreen_deadline', true);
echo $test;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
global $post;
$meta_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'offer_voucher_evergreen_deadline', true);
if( !empty($meta_value) ) {
   update_post_meta($post->ID, 'offer_voucher_evergreen_deadline', '2018-11-16 13:00:00');
}else {
   add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'offer_voucher_evergreen_deadline', '2018-11-16 13:00:00')
}

$test = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'offer_voucher_evergreen_deadline', true);
echo $test; //return $test;
```

Note: Use a 3'rd param in `get_post_meta()` function, which will return a single value

```
$test = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'offer_voucher_evergreen_deadline', true);
echo $test; //return $test;
```

See [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function for more details.

Comment: Saw this before you answered, adding true displays nothing so it must be the issue with adding the post meta.

Comment: Never mind I found where it was echo'ing it, although I found it just before your answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: ok, great to know that you figure it out. you can share your fix. Also, I have updated the answer.

Comment: I made a new post for another issue relating to this, feel free to check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863861/wordpress-on-edit-post-page-save-update-post-meta